# Issue with formula field, first condition works when the third condition is not added

Tags: formula, formula-field

I have been trying hard for hours now, I had an issue with the syntax, that is solved here [https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/357454/error-on-salesforce-custom-formula-field-says-extra-comma?noredirect=1#comment520345_357454](http://Syntax%20Issue).

I have this formula on a custom field

```
If(
    TEXT(Test.Cold.Type__c) = '' 
    || ISPICKVAL(Sale__r.Test__c, 'Sold') 
    || TEXT(Test.Cold.Type_Set__c) = ''
),0,1).
```

If I just do as below with first two condition, it works,

```
If(
    TEXT(Test.Cold.Type__c) = '' 
    || ISPICKVAL(Sale__r.Test__c, 'Sold'),0,1)
```

but if I add the third condition which is || `TEXT(Test.Cold.Type_Set__c) = ''`, the first condition does not work. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

There was one extra `)`. Because of this it is not working. You remove it and update the formula as below.

```
IF(OR( ISBLANK( TEXT(Test.Cold.Type__c) ),ISPICKVAL(Sale__r.Test__c, 'Sold') ,ISBLANK( TEXT(Test.Cold.Type_Set__c)) ),0,1)
```

Comment: There were no syntax errors. It is just not working as expected.

Comment: Can you update the formula as above and check. Because i see the syntax error there. if any of the above three conditions meet the value should be 0 or else it should be 1. Is this the requirement?

Comment: Maybe that was a copy paste error. The logic is exactly as you said.

Comment: Insted of || operator did you tried OR condition and also TEXT(Test.Cold.Type__c) = ''  insted of this replace it with ISBLANK(TEXT(Test.Cold.Type__c)). The same way with the other null check as well. This should resolve your issue

Comment: Try using this formula. Hope this will work. `If( 
    OR( ISBLANK( TEXT(Test.Cold.Type__c) ) ,
    ISPICKVAL(Sale__r.Test__c, 'Sold') ,
    ISBLANK( TEXT(Test.Cold.Type_Set__c))
),0,1)`

Comment: Yes I tried all that, it didn't work for me. Somebody helped me out with this, I will put the answer later today.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was about not grouping the first two conditions. This way it worked for me.

```
If((TEXT(Test.Cold.Type__c) = '' || ISPICKVAL(Sale__r.Test__c, 'Sold')) && TEXT(Test.Cold.Type_Set__c) = ''),0,1)
```